# Splitting column by delimiter into multiple columns (unknown number of columns)

Tags: split

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxCrW.png)

Hello!  The data frame shown in picture has column "Source", i'd like to split that column into multiple columns split by the _

I don't know how many columns it'll be as they string varies and is not fixed..

I've tried the separate function but not quite working as I'd hope.